# Вместо русских символов выводятся знаки вопросов в таблицах базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

В php storm подключил базу данных, создал файл в котором разместил скрипт создания и занесения данных, примерно таким образом:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS director
(
    ID int not null auto_increment,
    NAME varchar(500) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    );
INSERT INTO director (ID, NAME)
VALUES (1, 'Кристофер Нолан'),
       (2, 'Ли Анкрич'),
       (3, 'Оливье Накаш');
```

Затем через терминал запустил файл такой командой:
`Get-Content install-sql/install.sql | mysql -u root -p movie`
В результате, открываю таблицу и вижу следующее.
При этом латиница и цифры отображаются корректно. Как можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причём пробовал вставлять данные в эти же таблицы напрямую из консоли, тогда буквы отображаются.

Comment: Используйте кодировку utf8_general_ci

Comment: А как и где её можно задать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%5Bmysql%5D%5Bphp%5D

Comment: @VladimirGonchar и получите знаки вопроса на каких нибудь других расширенных символах. `urf8mb4_*` нынче пользуют

Comment: `name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci `

Comment: Скорее всего, кодировка, в которой написан файл скрипта, и кодировка, в которой создана таблица, не совпадают. Судя по количеству символов, файл скрипта написан в кодировке utf8, поэтому каждый русский символ передаётся двумя байтами. А база данных и консоль работают в кодировке windows-1251. Консоль не может интерпретировать двухбайтовые символы и выдаёт вместо них два вопроса.